# DeferRefresh is not allowed error if calling ListCollectionView.AddNewItem. Why?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have the following WPF application.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window 
    x:Class="DeferRefreshTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="system:String">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace DeferRefreshTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var names = new[] { "A name" };
            Names = new ListCollectionView(new List<string>());
            AddNames(names);

            DataContext = this;
        }

        void AddNames(IEnumerable<string> names)
        {
            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                Names.AddNewItem(name);
            }
        }

        public ListCollectionView Names { get; }
    }
}
```

When running the application, I get the following exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message='DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.DeferRefresh()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SetCollectionView(CollectionView view)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SetItemsSource(IEnumerable value, Func`2 GetSourceItem)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt attempt)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at DeferRefreshTest.App.Main()
```

I can fix the error by changing

```
Names = new ListCollectionView(new List<string>());
AddNames(names);
```

to

```
Names = new ListCollectionView(new List<string>(names));
//AddNames(names);
```

My question is, why does this error occur?

(Stack Overflow says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.", so I have added this redundant text. Please ignore.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the `AddNewItem` method *starts* an add transaction. You should call `CommitNew()` or `CancelNew()` to end each transaction:

```
void AddNames(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        Names.AddNewItem(name);
        Names.CommitNew();
    }
}
```